# Converting array of PFFile to UIImage in for loop returns empty array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, uiimage

I ma trying to take an array of type PFFile and convert into an array of type UIImage. I use the below code and no matter what it always returns an empty array. Any help is much appreciated.

userImagesPassed is an array of type PFFile.

```
func setUserImages() -> Array<UIImage> {
    var userImageArray = [UIImage]()
    for file2 in userImagesPassed {
        file2.getDataInBackground(block: { (imageData2, error) in
            if error != nil {
                userImageArray = []
            } else {
                userImageArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData2!)!)
            }
        })
    }
    return userImageArray
}
```

EDIT:

If I print the userImageArray inside the for loop I get the correct output (a populated array of type UIImage). But the returned value is still an empty array.

Comment: Hint: "asynchronous"

Comment: Thank you, I have tried but am probably doing it improperly. Would I be correct to put the for loop inside the asynchronous command?

Comment: Its because `return userImageArray` will call before any image downloaded.

Comment: Thanks @DharmeshKheni but I'm unsure how to fix that, moving the return statement causes an error.

Comment: Help me to understand what is use of `setUserImages()` here.

Comment: Thanks, setUserImages() takes an array of PFFiles and converts them into an array of UIImages which are then used to populate UIImageViews in an iOS application.

Comment: Then you need to wait until all images get downloaded.

Comment: @rmaddy Could you provide an example of the proper way to use the async method? I have tried in every configuration I can think of and still can't seem to get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first of all you **shouldn't use** **return** statement for async functions. You should use **completion handlers** to get your items back. This is the example how I get images from Parse and append to array.

**Swift 4.0**

```
    public func getImages(_ completion: @escaping (([UIImage]) -> Void)) {
    guard let tempImages = self.images else { return }
    var images = [UIImage]()
    for image in tempImages {
        image.getDataInBackground() {
            ( imageData, error) in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            guard let imageData = imageData else { return }
            guard let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else { return }
            images.append(image)
        }
    }
    completion(images) // Its returning your images
}
```

You can call your getImages function like this;

```
let images = self.yourObjectArrayInClass[(indexPath).row]
    images.getImages() {
        (images) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Do something with your images.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, a few questions as I'm not too familiar with using closures in this way. In the line `guard let tempImages = self.images else { return }` would `images` be my array of PFFiles? And when you call your `getImages` function it seems like your supposed to pass in an array of UIImages.

Comment: guard let statement for get the optional values from your database. They like if let statement but better way. You can google them. Did my answer solve your problem ? If it did. Please accept the answer. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, my images are already downloaded from Parse and put into an array of PFFiles, how would I pass that array into your solution? I have tried but get error because it expects an array of UIImages?